# Check if current date one day/one month/one week from specified date php/laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date

So I am trying to schedule a function to get called either daily/weekly or monthly. I have a current date from the database (format is 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm' if that's of any important). I want to check if current date is exactly one day/one week/one month from that date. I'm really new to php/laravel so I have no idea how to do this just yet, hence no code :(.

The type of my current date is DateTime

Comment: Without more information on your function and how it will be called it's hard to say, but I imagine you will find it difficult to ensure it is always called and called no more than once on the day/week/month in question. Why not use cron or a similar job scheduler designed for the task?

Answer (score 2):

In php you can check it by use DateTime

```
$d1 = new DateTime();
$d2 = new DateTime();
$interval = $d2->diff($d1);
echo $interval->y; // count if year between dates
echo $interval->days; // count if days between dates
```

Answer (score 0):

**Task Scheduling in Laravel >= 5.1 -**
The Laravel command scheduler allows you to manage your task execution dates and times using easily understandable PHP syntax and only a single Cron entry is needed on your server.

Your task schedule is defined in the `app/Console/Kernel.php` file's schedule method.

Of course, there are a variety of schedules you may assign to your task:

```
Method                      Description
===================================================
->cron('* * * * * *');      Run the task on a custom Cron schedule
->everyMinute();            Run the task every minute
->everyFiveMinutes();       Run the task every five minutes
->everyTenMinutes();        Run the task every ten minutes
->everyThirtyMinutes();     Run the task every thirty minutes
->hourly();                 Run the task every hour
->daily();                  Run the task every day at midnight
->dailyAt('13:00');         Run the task every day at 13:00
->twiceDaily(1, 13);        Run the task daily at 1:00 & 13:00
->weekly();                 Run the task every week
->monthly();                Run the task every month
->yearly();                 Run the task every year
```

For more reference see this link - https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling

Hope this will help you !!